# Numpy array interface with ctypes function

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I'm trying to interface a shared C library to some python code. 
The interface with the library is something like

```
typedef struct{
    int v1;
    double* v2} input;
```

There are two other types like this one: for configuration and the output type.

I set up these structs in python using `ctypes Structure`s like this:

```
class input(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("v1",c_int),("v2",POINTER(c_double)]
```

The C code have some functions that receive a pointer to that structure and the argtypes are defined as in:

```
fun.argtypes = [constraints,input,POINTER(input)]
```

`constraints` is another structure with some `int` fields for configuration.

First I update the v2 field in the input struct

```
input.v2 = generated_array.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
```

Then I call it:

```
fun(constraints,input,byref(output))
```

The function prototype  asks for struct and * to struct (output struct type is assumed to be the same as the input struct type).

Then I want to access the results of fun stored in the v2 field of output. But I'm getting unexpected results. Is there a better/correct way of do this?

I searched a lot here and read the documentation but I can't find what's wrong. I don't have any error messages, but the warnings that I receive from the shared lib seems to show that there are mistakes on these interfaces.

---

I guess I have found the problem:

When I call the method a numpy array of complex is called. Then I create 4 vectors:

```
    out_real = ascontiguousarray(zeros(din.size,dtype=c_double))
    out_imag = ascontiguousarray(zeros(din.size,dtype=c_double))
    in_real  = ascontiguousarray(din.real,dtype = c_double)
    in_imag  = ascontiguousarray(din.imag,dtype = c_double)
```

where din is the input vector. I had tested the method this way:

```
    print in_real.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))    
    print in_imag.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
    print out_real.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
    print out_imag.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
```

and the result was:

```
    <model.LP_c_double object at 0x1d81f80>
    <model.LP_c_double object at 0x1d81f80>
    <model.LP_c_double object at 0x1d81f80>
    <model.LP_c_double object at 0x1d81f80>
```

It seems that all of them are pointing to the same place.

After some changes, it works as expected...

---

After several tests I found that the code was nearly correct the first time. I was creating the Structure instance once and updating its fields. I changed to creating a new instance at each call of `fun`. I also changed all arrays types to be the equivalent ctypes type; this seemed to make the function work as expected.

The print behavior still holds as in the test above, but the function seems to work even with this strange behavior. **It is correct as pointed by @ericsun comment below.**

Comment: Please post full code, what does the c code do?

Comment: Sadly I can't share the full code since it's a thirdy party library under nda. But it's just a scientific algorithm that takes  two vectors and return other 2 vectors. Do you think the question is not clear without the full description?

Comment: the c function interface is not clear, the `fun.argtypes = [...,POINTER(input)]` and `fun(..,input,byref(output))` is not the same interface.

Comment: I see. I'll update to make it clear.

Comment: About the `LP_c_double` objects, that's the Python object address, not the address in the pointer. You only printed a temporary pointer object; at the next print it was already deallocated and the same address was reused. Look at the `contents` attribute, or just the `[0]` index.

Comment: I see, I was trying to look at the address to make sure that it's pointing to the correct place. The indexing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `struct` has an `int` field that's possibly for the array length, though I'm just guessing without the complete function prototype. If this is indeed the case, here's an example that may help.

First, I need to compile a test function in a shared library. I'll simply multiply the input array by 2:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from ctypes import *

open('tmp.c', 'w').write('''\
typedef struct {
    int v1; double *v2;
} darray;
int test(darray *input, darray *output) {
    int i;
    /* note: this should first test for compatible size */
    for (i=0; i < input->v1; i++)
        *(output->v2 + i) = *(input->v2 + i) * 2;
    return 0;
}
''')
os.system('gcc -shared -o tmp.so tmp.c')
```

Next create the ctypes definitions. I added a `classmethod` to make a `darray` from a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
c_double_p = POINTER(c_double)

class darray(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ('v1', c_int),
      ('v2', c_double_p),
    ]
    @classmethod
    def fromnp(cls, a):
        return cls(len(a), a.ctypes.data_as(c_double_p))

lib = CDLL('./tmp.so')
lib.test.argtypes = POINTER(darray), POINTER(darray)
```

Test:

```
a1 = np.arange(3) + 1.0
a2 = np.zeros(3)
print 'before:', '\na1 =', a1, '\na2 =', a2 

lib.test(darray.fromnp(a1), darray.fromnp(a2))
print 'after:', '\na1 =', a1, '\na2 =', a2
```

Output:

```
before: 
a1 = [ 1.  2.  3.] 
a2 = [ 0.  0.  0.]
after: 
a1 = [ 1.  2.  3.] 
a2 = [ 2.  4.  6.]
```

Comment: This code is very close of mine. But instead of creating a new instance each time the function is called I just update the fields I need when I call the method fun(I had the c code encapsulated in a class). I also didn't have c_double_p as in the code. I call POINTER(c_double) when needed. I'll try this modifications.

Comment: @EuripedesRochaFilho: You didn't show how the `v1` field is used. This answer sets it as the array length in the `fromnp` `classmethod`: `cls(len(a), a.ctypes.data_as(c_double_p))`. Making that a method and assigning `c_double_p` were just for convenience. I also showed that it's modifying the `ndarray` objects' buffers. You only need these `Structure` instances for the call. Access the data via the NumPy arrays.

Comment: You're right guessing about the v1 field as the size of v2. I'm also using numpy array to have access to results. I was just updating the fields since in my task now I need to call the function several times. I'm testing with creating a new instance of the Structures on each call, but just because I'm on the supernatural tests now :)

Comment: @eryksun: How could I extend this nice example for a matrix structure?
typedef struct{int v1,v2; 
double ** v3
}matrix;

Comment: @JonatasEduardo,  a NumPy matrix defaults to a C contiguous array. This is a row-major structure, i.e. think of it as the rows concatenated into a single array. (It's not a `double **` array of `double *` pointers to the rows.) So use `double *v3` with a nested for loop, where `i` is the row index and `j` is the column index. If `v2` is the number of columns, then the `[i, j]` element is either `input->v3[i * input->v2 + j]` or `*(input->v3 + i * input->v2 + j)`, whichever syntax you prefer.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you very much, [here](https://gist.github.com/jonataseduardo/acead327a67b24c04acf) is a gist with an workaround using your example